# Value not received from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made a web app.  I wanted to capture a few additional fields. But, the additional fields are not getting captured.

Code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DependentSelect');
  var colors = getColors();
  htmlOutput.message = '';
  htmlOutput.colors = colors;
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

function doPost(e) {
  
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  
  var name = e.parameters.name.toString();
  var mobile = e.parameters.mobile.toString();
  var typ = e.parameters.typ.toString();    
  var color = e.parameters.color.toString();
  var fruit = e.parameters.fruit.toString();
  var dis = e.parameters.dis.toString();
  
  AddRecord(name, mobile, typ, dis, color, fruit);
  
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DependentSelect');
  var colors = getColors();
  htmlOutput.message = 'Record Added';
  htmlOutput.colors = colors;
  return htmlOutput.evaluate(); 
}
//
function getColors() { 
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bff_zH-C9VramZq-nSJzlyQ-ZZDLyOZNcZwrLfBbVlE/edit#gid=0';//jd products
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);  
  //var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lovSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Products"); 
  var getLastRow = lovSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
      if(return_array.indexOf(lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue()) === -1) {
        return_array.push(lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue());
      }
  }
  return return_array;  
}
//
function getFruits(color) { 
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bff_zH-C9VramZq-nSJzlyQ-ZZDLyOZNcZwrLfBbVlE/edit#gid=0';//jd products
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  //var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lovSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Products"); 
  var getLastRow = lovSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
      if(lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() === color) {
        return_array.push(lovSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue());
      }
  }
  return return_array;  
}
//
function AddRecord(name, mobile, typ, dis, color, fruit) {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MMQFv1-8P7EQ3ymYsk_c1eYmsISJeGbI2hxB-MqRBCI/edit#gid=983363487';//jd data
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Web_Data");
  dataSheet.appendRow([new Date(), name, mobile, typ, color, fruit, dis]);
}
//
function getUrl() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 return url;
}
```

DependentSelect.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function GetFruit(color) 
    {
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
    {

    console.log(ar);
    
    fruit.length = 0;
    
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "";
    fruit.appendChild(option);
    
    ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
    {    
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item;
      option.text = item;
      fruit.appendChild(option);    
    });
    
    }).getFruits(color);
    
    };
  </script>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Buy or Sell Products</h1>
    <?var url = getUrl();?>
    <form method="post" action="<?= url ?>" >
      <label style="font-size: 20px" >Your Name or Company Name</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="name" style="font-size: 20px" /><br><br>

      <label style="font-size: 20px" >Mobile no (ten digits) for whatsapp</label><br>
      <input type="text" mobile="mobile" style="font-size: 20px" /><br><br>

      <label style="font-size: 20px" >Buy or Sell</label><br>
      <input type="text" typ="typ" style="font-size: 20px" /><br><br>

      <label style="font-size: 20px" >Product</label><br>
      <select name="color" style="font-size: 20px" onchange="GetFruit(this.value)" >
      <option value="" ></option>
      <? for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) { ?>      
      <option value="<?= colors[i] ?>" ><?= colors[i] ?></option>
      <? } ?>
      </select><br><br>
      
      <label style="font-size: 20px" >Category</label><br>
      <select name="fruit" id="fruit" style="font-size: 20px" >
      </select><br><br>

      <label style="font-size: 20px" >Discription</label><br>
      <input type="text" dis="dis" style="font-size: 20px" /><br><br>

      <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" style="font-size: 20px" /> 
      <span style="font-size: 20px" ><?= message ?></span>      
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined (line 14, file "Code")

is coming, pertains to

var mobile = e.parameters.mobile.toString();

Not able to find why the "mobile" is not passed to the function.

Comment: not sure why you're using random attribute names like `mobile`, `typ`, `dis` - what you want is `name ="mobile"` `name ="typ"` and `name="dis"` - `name` is a standard attribute that names an element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a small change to your HTML forms' input elements. Add the "name" attribute to each, instead of a random attribute name.

For example, change

> `<input type="text" dis="dis" style="font-size: 20px" />`

to

> `<input type="text" name="dis" style="font-size: 20px" />`

Now your `e.parameters.<name of your param>` will always exist and the error you see won't be thrown.